# 3TB SAS drives connected through an LSI HBA card/Supermicro backplane are unable to be formated in disks/gparted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-management

I am running ubuntu desktop 20.04 and I have an LSI 9207-8i HBA card (flashed to IT mode) that is connected to a Supermicro SAS826-7EL1 backplane. There are 12: 3TB IBM SAS drives attached to the backplane as well as another SAS/SATA breakout cable daisy chained from the backplane with 4: 4TB drives attached. disk management is discovering all of these drives, however only the 4: 4TB SATA drives are accessible to read/write to. I have tried to format partitions on the SAS drives in disk management, parted, and gparted. disk management returns the error: "Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdf' (udisks-error-quark, 0)". Gparted/Parted return input/output errors as well.

Now, I am definitely a newbie in the server space and very well may have bought the wrong backplane for these 3TB drives, as it seems as though it is SAS instead of SAS2. However, I am not sure why all of the devices would be discoverable within disk management if the backplane was not able to at least interact with the drives themselves.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1341310/edit) and add the new information.

Comment: https://www.linux.org/threads/error-wiping-device-failed-to-probe-the-device-udisks-error-quark-0.26217/This link may help you out: